# How to run a query with regexp in Android

Tags: android, regex, sqlite

I want to run a query in `SQLite` with a `regexp` using `Android`.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like Android currently supplies a way for you to inject a user function into sqlite, which is what you'd need to make `REGEXP` work (specifically, you'd need a user function named `regexp()`) -- so you may have to select more broadly (with a `LIKE` condition that's broader than the regexp you want) and further distinguish "actual" result (those that really match the regexp you want) with `java.util.regex` in your application.

Answer (score -3):

> Patterns are compiled regular expressions. In many cases, convenience
>   methods such as String.matches, String.replaceAll and String.split
>   will be preferable, but if you need to do a lot of work with the same
>   regular expression, it may be more efficient to compile it once and
>   reuse it. The Pattern class and its companion, Matcher, also offer
>   more functionality than the small amount exposed by String.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html