# Search SQLite database in android with regional chars (pt_PT) and case insensitive

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-like

How to search a table (tbl) with this records:

```
_id   name
----- ----------
1     antónio
2     antonio
3     antõnio
4     ANTONIO
5     ANTÓNIO

select * from tbl where name like "%to%" COLLATE LOCALIZED;
```

The result is:

```
_id   name
----- ----------
2     antonio
4     ANTONIO
```

but the result must be all 5 records!

Comment: this is for SQLite in Android environment, Latin1_General_CI_AI_WS seems to be for MSSQL server.

Comment: Found 2 approaches [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841694/how-to-sql-compare-columns-when-one-has-accented-chars) but no easy one.