# SQLite LIKE statement with special characters

Tags: sqlite, special-characters

I am trying to run a search query on my SQLite db and am having problems with special characters that are stored.

I have a column called site_name which contains records like castle, chàteau, church. When someone uses chateau as their search term I want it to pull out the chàteau record.

Is there a method for handling this in SQLite?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841694/how-to-sql-compare-columns-when-one-has-accented-chars)

The link references Android development, but it appears to answer your question.

Comment: Okay thanks, My project is for iOS. I presume the best solution is to create a new column for normalized strings

Comment: Agreed. Doing all of those replace statements every time you query that table would be costly and unnecessary if you can do it once and be done with it. Please upvote or mark this as the answer if you think it helped solve your problem.