# LIKE query not working as expected

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have an SQL Query that looks like:

> SELECT "medical_interventions"."id" AS t0_r0,
>   "medical_interventions"."refcode" AS t0_r1,
>   "medical_interventions"."intervention_tid" AS t0_r2,
>   "medical_interventions"."medical_intervention_category_id" AS t0_r3,
>   "medical_interventions"."created_at" AS t0_r4,
>   "medical_interventions"."updated_at" AS t0_r5, "translations"."id" AS
>   t1_r0, "translations"."lang" AS t1_r1, "translations"."text" AS t1_r2,
>   "translations"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "translations"."updated_at" AS
>   t1_r4 FROM "medical_interventions" LEFT OUTER JOIN "translations" ON
>   "translations"."id" = "medical_interventions"."intervention_tid" AND
>   "translations"."lang" = 'fr' WHERE (medical_intervention_category_id
>   =7 AND text like '%é%')

I have a text in there labeled `évaluer`

When I search fore just `é` as in the query above, I get `évaluer` as I expect. However, if I try év:

> SELECT "medical_interventions"."id" AS t0_r0,
>   "medical_interventions"."refcode" AS t0_r1,
>   "medical_interventions"."intervention_tid" AS t0_r2,
>   "medical_interventions"."medical_intervention_category_id" AS t0_r3,
>   "medical_interventions"."created_at" AS t0_r4,
>   "medical_interventions"."updated_at" AS t0_r5, "translations"."id" AS
>   t1_r0, "translations"."lang" AS t1_r1, "translations"."text" AS t1_r2,
>   "translations"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "translations"."updated_at" AS
>   t1_r4 FROM "medical_interventions" LEFT OUTER JOIN "translations" ON
>   "translations"."id" = "medical_interventions"."intervention_tid" AND
>   "translations"."lang" = 'fr' WHERE (medical_intervention_category_id
>   =7 AND text like '%év%')

I get absolutely no results.

Is there something I do not understand about LIKE? Is there an alternate function I could use for searches?

```
AR:
    def self.find_by_search_query_and_problem_id(search_query, problem_id)
        problem = Problem.find(problem_id)
        category = ProblemCategory.find(problem.category_id)
        medIntCategory = MedicalInterventionCategory.find_by_category_text(category.category.text)

        search = search_query
        query = "medical_intervention_category_id =" + medIntCategory.id.to_s + " AND text like ?"
        return self.includes(:intervention).where(query, "%#{search}%").references(:intervention)
    end
```

In the controller

```
def search
    @interventions = MedicalIntervention.find_by_search_query_and_problem_id(URI.unescape(params[:search_query]),params[:problem_id])
end
```

In JS:

```
getInterventionsFromSearch: function(search_query, problem_id) 
{
    var interventions = new MedicalIntervetionsCollection();
    // fetch data on url AJAX
    if(search_query != "")
    {
        interventions.url = "medical_interventions_search?search_query="+encodeURIComponent(search_query) + 
        "&problem_id=" + problem_id;
        interventions.fetch();
    }
    return interventions;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me your AR query ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9fbfa/1: I don´t think the problem is related to the LIKE.... something else is going on.... encoding?

Comment: @gabrielhilal I added the rest of the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post: [How to SQL compare columns when one has accented chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841694/how-to-sql-compare-columns-when-one-has-accented-chars/2841737#2841737)

Another idea:

There is an easy solution, but not very elegant.

Use the `REPLACE` function, to remove your accents. Exemple:

```
SELECT YOUR_COLUMN FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace( lower(YOUR_COLUMN), 'á','a'), 'ã','a'), 'â','a'), 'é','e'), 'ê','e'), 'í','i'),
'ó','o') ,'õ','o') ,'ô','o'),'ú','u'), 'ç','c') LIKE 'SEARCH_KEY%'
```

Where `SEARCH_KEY` is the key word that you wanna find on the column.

Or:

A possible solution would be a User-Defined-Function (UDF). There is a document [here](http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/upgrading+php+5/Chapter+4.+SQLite/4.6+User-Defined+Functions/) describing how to create such a function for SQLite in PHP. You could write a function called DROPACCENTS()

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my response with some ideas for you.