# How to achieve word boundary in Sqlite Android?

Tags: android, regex, sqlite, word-boundary

I would like to achieve the following (a full text search),

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where columnname REGEXP '[[:<:]]some string[[:>:]]'
```

Where i am interested in only exact strings (not just words) from a full text column.

I have been using the exact SQL above in MySQL and now migrating most of the code to android apps.

But I have been looking at various posts where it is mentioned that REGEXP isn't supported in Android Sqlite (for example: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266515/how-to-search-sqlite-database-using-regular-expression-in-android), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047342/how-to-run-a-query-with-regexp-in-android), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037982/how-used-regexp-in-sqlite) ).

Is there a way to enable REGEXP in Android?

**If not are there any alternatives for the above SQL?**

Thank you,

**EDIT:**
Currently I am receiving the following exception when using REGEXP in Android,

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: REGEXP (code 1):...
```

I understand we can make use of GLOB and LIKE ( or may be even MATCH ). How can `columnname REGEXP '[[:<:]]somestring[[:>:]]'` be converted to make use of `GLOB` and/or `LIKE` and/or `MATCH`?

**SOLUTION 1**:
With [@cybersam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28228702/677607)'s help following is what I am using (after some modifications)

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where
  (columnname GLOB '*some string*' OR columnname GLOB '*Some string*') AND 
(
(
    (columnname GLOB '*[^a-zA-Z0-9_]some string[^a-zA-Z0-9_]*' AND
    columnname GLOB '*some string[^a-zA-Z0-9_]*' AND
    columnname GLOB '*[^a-zA-Z0-9_]some string*')
OR
    (columnname GLOB '*[^a-zA-Z0-9_]Some string[^a-zA-Z0-9_]*' AND
    columnname GLOB '*Some string[^a-zA-Z0-9_]*' AND
    columnname GLOB '*[^a-zA-Z0-9_]Some string*')
)
)
```

`GLOB` is case-sensitive so I have an additional `OR`

[@cybersam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28228702/677607)'s second solution is much faster in my case.

**SOLUTION 2**: To handle case in-sensitivity

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where
  (columnname GLOB '*[sS][oO][mM][eE] [sS][tT][rR][iI][nN][gG]*') AND 
(
    (
    columnname GLOB '*[^a-zA-Z0-9_][sS][oO][mM][eE] [sS][tT][rR][iI][nN][gG][^a-zA-Z0-9_]*' AND 
    columnname GLOB '*[sS][oO][mM][eE] [sS][tT][rR][iI][nN][gG][^a-zA-Z0-9_]*' AND 
    columnname GLOB '*[^a-zA-Z0-9_][sS][oO][mM][eE] [sS][tT][rR][iI][nN][gG]*')
)
```

Comment: try this `\<somestring\>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To actually support `REGEXP`, you will have to add your own [regexp() user function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp).

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867099/how-can-i-create-a-user-defined-function-in-sqlite) might help you figure out how to create user defined functions, in general, for Android -- but it is not simple.

If your patterns are very simple, the [GLOB operator](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#glob) might be good enough.

For example, to perform a search equivalent to this MYSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where columnname REGEXP '[[:<:]]some string[[:>:]]'
```

you can try this in SQLite:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where
  columnname GLOB '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]some string[^a-zA-Z0-9_]' OR
  columnname GLOB 'some string[^a-zA-Z0-9_]' OR
  columnname GLOB '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]some string' OR
  columnname GLOB 'some string';
```

The above query uses the fact that in MYSQL, a word character is defined to be either an alphanumeric character or an underscore. The additional `OR` terms are needed to also match the cases where there is no text on either (or both) sides of `some string`.

Finally, if 'some string' is relatively rare in `columnname`, then the following longer query may actually be faster, since it will only do multiple `GLOB` evaluations for a minority of values:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where
  columnname GLOB '*some string*' AND (
    columnname GLOB '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]some string[^a-zA-Z0-9_]' OR
    columnname GLOB 'some string[^a-zA-Z0-9_]' OR
    columnname GLOB '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]some string' OR
    columnname GLOB 'some string');
```